# How to return multiples lines in a shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode

I found this example of a shortcode on the Internet:

```
function project_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => '',
        'id' => '',
        ), $atts ) );

        return '<div id="' . $id . '" class="' . $class . '">' . $content . '</div>';

}
add_shortcode('button', 'project_shortcode');
```

This is the output I want:

```
<div class="container item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="intro twelvecol">
            <div class="top-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="screenshot eightcol">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/studyatbest.png">
        </div>
        <div class="screenshot fourcol last">
            <h3>BEST LANGUAGE CENTER</h3>
            <p>BEST Language Center is an educational establishment in Taichung, Taiwan. I was asked to build and design a website they could use to offer classes, programs and display photos online.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h4>ROLE</h4>
                    <p>Design, HTML/CSS, JavaScript</p>
                <li>
                    <h4>YEAR</h4>
                    <p>2010</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4>WEBSITE</h4>
                    <p><a href="http://studyatbest.com/">studyatbest.com</a></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to do it so that I can return multiples lines in the shortcode (in order to keep the code clean). Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your input for the shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use output buffering. It is too slow and sometimes hard to debug. Use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Example:

```php
$output = <<<MYUNIQUENAME
    <div>$foo
      <p>Some $bar</p>
    </div>
MYUNIQUENAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
// Project shortcode
function project_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'client' => '',
        'screenshot' => '',
        'role' => '',
        'year' => '',
        'website' => '',
        ), $atts ) );

        ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="container item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="intro twelvecol">
                <div class="top-border"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="screenshot eightcol">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/<?php echo $screenshot ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="screenshot fourcol last">
                <h3><?php echo $client ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h4>ROLE</h4>
                        <p><?php echo $role ?></p>
                    <li>
                        <h4>YEAR</h4>
                        <p><?php echo $year ?></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>WEBSITE</h4>
                        <p><a href="http://<?php echo $website ?>"><?php echo $website ?></a></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('project', 'project_shortcode');
```

(Please tell me if there is any bad practice in that code).